# Creating a new line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a script to auto install openvpn. The last thing I have to do is insert the configuration file to auto start. I have tried using sed to simply search for a line before where I'm looking to insert my new but it doesn't seem to be working, I think due to the quotation marks in the command.

Do what I have is:

```
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office”
```

Then I run my sed command:

```
sed -i 's/home office"/home office"\n AUTORUN="Netherlands"/' openvpn
```

I've looked around and tried escaping my double quote marks to see if that was the issue, but that didn't work out.

My end goal is to have:

```
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office”
AUTOSTART=“Netherlands”
```

Comment: Is this part of a bigger configuration file? If not, why don't you just append a new row? `echo 'AUTOSTART="Netherlands"' >> myfile`

Comment: Yes, there is more to the file under all this. So that won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ sed 's/"home office"/&\nAUTOSTART="Netherlands"/' file.txt 
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office"
AUTOSTART="Netherlands"
```

I assumed you meant `"` instead of `”`.

If you meant `”` :

```
$ sed 's/"home office”/&\nAUTOSTART=”Netherlands”/' file.txt 
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office”
AUTOSTART=”Netherlands”
```

Comment: That's what I needed that.
On a side note I hadn't even noticed that the quote mark had changed to an end quote there.Thanks.

Comment: The opening quote is also "smart" and different from the closing one in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to substitute anything. `sed` can add text after the desired line.

```
sed -i '/home office/a\
AUTOSTART="Netherlands"\
' openvpn
```